# Heroku Login Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm trying to use Heroku CLI on Mac.

When I try to login to Heroku using Heroku login and give my credentials, I get the below error:

> Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it several times, but I continue to receive this error.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing issue same issue because of my organization firewall. Solution is to simply [download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940396/how-to-export-certificate-from-chrome-on-a-mac) and install organization certs.

1. Once you download organization specific ".cer" file then convert that file to ".pem" using

   `openssl x509 -inform der -in orgCertFile.cer -out certificate.pem`
2. Next, set following variable either as system variable or temp variable in current command line

   `export SSL_CERT_FILE=orgCertFile.cer`

   `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=certificate.pem`
3. Finally try logging in using heroku command

   `heroku login`

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means you're behind a mitm proxy that isn't configured right. [See the docs for details](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy).