# Heroku create - self_signed_cert_in_chain

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I am struggling to get my first app created on Heroku.
I finally got past the login self signed certificate in certificates chain by following this:
[Heroku Login Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885187/heroku-login-error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain)

But now I can receiving a similar error when attempting to create the app.

```
Creating app... !
 !    SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Using whoami, I can see that I am logged in.

(First post on Stack! So any suggestions to improve my posting is welcome!)
Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to add, this is a Windows system.

Comment: I was able to get  around the error by setting the environ variable HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable