# How to save SSL certificate by chrome and firefox on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl, firefox, certificate

This blog explains how to save SSL certificate in chrome and firefox. But I can not following it (my os is Mac). I am not sure if this is because of the difference between mac and windows. Could anybody show me how to save SSL certificate on Mac?

https://medium.com/@menakajain/export-download-ssl-certificate-from-server-site-url-bcfc41ea46a2

Answer (score 22):

The interfaces are a little different in the macOS versions.

**In Safari:**

1. Click the padlock icon in the URL bar
2. Click the Show Certificate button in the dialog that appears
3. Click on the certificate icon, and drag it to a Finder window (or the Desktop)

**In Google Chrome:**

1. Click the padlock icon in the URL bar
2. If the dialog that appears has a "Connection is secure" line, click on that
3. Click the "Certificate is valid" or "Certificate (Valid)" area in the dialog
4. If there is a certificate icon, and drag that to a Finder window (or the Desktop); if there isn't an icon, select the Details tab, then click Export.

**In Firefox:**

Firefox keeps changing the interface details, you may see something a little different from what I describe.

1. Click the padlock icon in the URL bar
2. Click the ">" or "Show connection details" button to the right of "Connection secure" in the dialog that appears
3. Click the "More information" area
4. Under the Security tab, click the "View Certificate" button
5. A "about:certificate?cert=..." browser tab will open. Depending on the Firefox version, it may have separate tabs for each of the certificates in the trust chain. The site's leaf certificate should be on the left, so you may need to select that
6. Scroll down to the Miscellaneous section. In the "Download" line, click "PEM (cert)" to save the specific certificate to your Downloads folder, or "PEM (chain)" to save the entire trust chain

Comment: Firefox: the button is no longer available in latest firefox

Comment: There is a "save" row where you can chose the PEM/PEM chain in Firefox v123.0.