# https call using Spring rest template causing SSL handshake?

Tags: java, spring

I have added below code in Spring bean config file:

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory"/>
</bean>
```

And in code, we're using below code to call service:

```
restTemplate.getForObject("https://xxxxx", ProductList.class);
```

We're getting error as: SSLHandShakeException:: Remote host closed connection during handshake.

Can you please let me know how to configure the https certificate and certificate password in the above code Spring rest template. Currently, we're using Spring 4.0 in our project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072585/disabling-ssl-certificate-validation-in-spring-resttemplate/61686589#61686589