# Java errors with certrificates, rest template

Tags: java, spring, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, resttemplate

I have a problem with certificates. Namely, I'm using 2 servers. On the first one is the service which I'm trying to call on the other. Error is:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://xxx":no more data allowed for version 1 certificate; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: no more data allowed for version 1 certificate

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: no more data allowed for version 1 certificate

10:35:08,479 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateMsg.<init>(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,480 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,481 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,481 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,482 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: no more data allowed for version 1 certificate

10:35:08,489 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,489 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,489 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,489 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,489 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,489 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)   at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(Unknown Source)

10:35:08,489 INFO  [stdout] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8443-1)
```

My code:

```
@Override
public void changeState(Device device) {            
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();  

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<Device> entity = new HttpEntity<Device>(device, httpHeaders);
    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Void.class);        
}
```

I have tried this solutions: [Disabling SSL Certificate Validation in Spring RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072585/disabling-ssl-certificate-validation-in-spring-resttemplate) but it didn't work for me. How can I ignore the certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to the beginning of your method. If so, move the code to the beginning of the application:

```
java.lang.System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "NONE");
```

Answer (score 0):

The server requires to have a certificate attached, but I don't see any ConnectionFactory with it created.

You need to load the certificate material and setup SSL with something like this:

```
HttpClient sslClient = HttpClients.custom()
                            .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                                          .build();

        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(sslClient);
        restTemplate().setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```