# Unable to send Post request with Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I´m trying to make a post request, according the code below:

```
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory csf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(csf).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
        
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("emailadress", "");
        map.put("emailSubject", "Pendência para lançamento de horas do Jira");
        map.put("emailBody", "Se você visualizar esta mensagem o bot funcionou");
        
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.add("Accept",MediaType.ALL_VALUE);
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map,requestHeaders);
        String url = new StringBuilder().append("...").toString();
        restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Void.class);
        logger.info("Bot enviado com sucesso!");
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao enviar Bot.", e);
        throw e;
    }
```

At the Postman, this request works fine and don´t needs authentication, it works without login, password or token. But, at the code above does not works.

A part of the log console is below:

```
lientExec - Executing request POST /workflows/fbf4c29cbcad4679b1a1159fff7b07f9/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%252Ftriggers%252Fmanual%252Frun&sv=1.0&sig=zxm46aQnBj3ZTKPOddnnwUgtQZoQcQfixNtXVxAJjPg HTTP/1.1
00:11:45.884 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
00:11:45.888 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
00:11:45.896 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /workflows/fbf4c29cbcad4679b1a1159fff7b07f9/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%252Ftriggers%252Fmanual%252Frun&sv=1.0&sig=zxm46aQnBj3ZTKPOddnnwUgtQZoQcQfixNtXVxAJjPg HTTP/1.1
00:11:45.896 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept: */*
00:11:45.896 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/json
00:11:45.896 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 168
00:11:45.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: prod-12.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443
00:11:45.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
00:11:45.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_261)
00:11:45.897 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
00:11:45.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /workflows/fbf4c29cbcad4679b1a1159fff7b07f9/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%252Ftriggers%252Fmanual%252Frun&sv=1.0&sig=zxm46aQnBj3ZTKPOddnnwUgtQZoQcQfixNtXVxAJjPg HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
00:11:45.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
00:11:45.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
00:11:45.898 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 168[\r][\n]"
00:11:45.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: prod-12.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443[\r][\n]"
00:11:45.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
00:11:45.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_261)[\r][\n]"
00:11:45.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
00:11:45.899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
00:11:45.900 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "{"emailadress":"jboscod@indracompany.com","emailBody":"Se voc[0xc3][0xaa] visualizar esta mensagem o bot funcionou","emailSubject":"Pend[0xc3][0xaa]ncia para lan[0xc3][0xa7]amento de horas do Jira"}"
00:11:46.340 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.341 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.343 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.345 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.345 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Expires: -1[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.346 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "x-ms-request-id: westeurope:bdf621fd-4e29-456d-bf2e-a07c209bd7ff[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.347 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.348 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Fri, 11 Sep 2020 03:10:47 GMT[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.348 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 253[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.349 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
00:11:46.351 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"You do not have permissions to perform action 'run' on scope '/triggers/manual/paths/'. Verify you are making the request with the appropriate HTTP method. See http://aka.ms/logic-trigger for details."}}"
00:11:46.422 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
00:11:46.423 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Cache-Control: no-cache
00:11:46.424 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Pragma: no-cache
00:11:46.425 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
00:11:46.427 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Expires: -1
00:11:46.427 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << x-ms-request-id: westeurope:bdf621fd-4e29-456d-bf2e-a07c209bd7ff
00:11:46.429 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
00:11:46.429 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Fri, 11 Sep 2020 03:10:47 GMT
00:11:46.429 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 253
00:11:46.546 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
00:11:46.546 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator - Authentication required
00:11:46.546 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator - prod-12.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443 requested authentication
00:11:46.547 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator - Response contains no authentication challenges
00:11:46.651 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED
00:11:46.688 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 0][route: {s}->https://prod-12.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443] can be kept alive indefinitely
00:11:46.688 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: set socket timeout to 0
00:11:46.689 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://prod-12.westeurope.logic.azure.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
```

I couldn´t paste the whole stacktrace because the stackoverflow platform don´t allow.

Comment: What's the error? Is it CORS or CSFR?

Comment: This is probably due to https.   Do you have ssl verification turned off in postman (which would allow the https request to go through)?  Can you post the stacktrace?  See this answer for how you can use a certificate with RestTemplate https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618150/1410671

Comment: I edit the question with the stacktrace.

Comment: According your comment, I made some changes at the code, but it still got 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Answer (score 0):

Actually you already have token in your request.
It should work by the following code (no need disable SSL or authentication, cuz you have token already)

```
try {
  RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("emailadress", "");
  map.put("emailSubject", "Pendência para lançamento de horas do Jira");
  map.put("emailBody", "Se você visualizar esta mensagem o bot funcionou");

  HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  requestHeaders.add("Accept",MediaType.ALL_VALUE);
  requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
  HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map,requestHeaders);
  String url = new StringBuilder()
          .append("...")
          .append("?api-version=").append("2016-06-01")
          .append("&sp=").append("/triggers/manual/run")
          .append("&sv=").append("1.0")
          .append("&sig=").append("zxm46aQnBj3ZTKPOddnnwUgtQZoQcQfixNtXVxAJjPg")
          .toString();
  restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Void.class);
  logger.info("Bot enviado com sucesso!");
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("Erro ao enviar Bot.", e);
  throw e;
}
```

Comment: Welcome, glad to hear that