# Ignore SSL Warnings with Apache HttpClient 4.5 and Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, hystrix

We have an internal service that we would like to start making calls to over HTTPS. The service is only available internally, so I'm not worried about accepting all self-signed warnings. This is what I'm using:

```
    BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =  new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(REST_USER, REST_PASS));
    SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
        @Override
        public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            return true;
        }
    });
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build(),
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(client);
    RestTemplate restTemplate =  new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost/addrgeo/standardUSAddresses": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I even tried creating a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`:

```
    BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =  new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(REST_USER, REST_PASS));

SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build(),SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> registry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
        .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
        .register("https", sslsf)
        .build();
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(registry);
cm.setMaxTotal(2000);//max connection

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
```

But I get the same error.

We are wrapping our calls with `Hystrix`, but I don't know why that would have any impact on the actual call itself.

I took a look at this question:

[Why can't I find the truststore for an SSL handshake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725863/why-cant-i-find-the-truststore-for-an-ssl-handshake)

But none of the answers seem to get me where I need to be.

What am I doing wrong?

## Solution

Well, I feel like a fool...

Turns out it was a weird caching issue with IntelliJ. Maven was still using the old source code. The solution was to close IntelliJ, run a `mvn clean install`, opening and invalidating caches in IntelliJ, and re-importing the project worked. For good measure, I also refreshed the file status under `VCS` and performed a Synchronize.